# 'str' object has no attribute 'save_screenshot'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a small python script that will call firefox and take screenshot at interval of 1/60 sec. The screenshot would be taken till end 120th sec.

Error - The script is able to take the first screenshot, however in the next one, I am getting the error `'str' object has no attribute 'save_screenshot'`.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading

counter = 0
def take_screenshot(driver):
    global counter
    print (type(counter))
    driver.save_screenshot("selenium-test_" + str(counter) + ".png")
    counter += 1
    if counter <= 7200:
        threading.Timer(1.0/60.0, take_screenshot,['driver']).start()
    else:
        driver.quit()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1083 ,557)
driver.get("file:///Users/tusharsaurabh/E%20Card/ecard-coconut-tree/index.html")
take_screenshot(driver)
```

Please let me know, where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here:

```
threading.Timer(1.0/60.0, take_screenshot,['driver']).start()
```

you feed it a string: `'driver'`. You can probably fix it with:

```
threading.Timer(1.0/60.0, take_screenshot,[driver]).start()
#                                          ^    ^
#                                         no quotes
```